# How to use dynamic list for Shadcn ui select component

Tags: reactjs, next.js, shadcnui

How can I use dynamic list for shadcn ui select component and probably loop over them as selectItems instead of hard coding them?

I used items.map() and tried looping over them, setting key in the SelectItem to item.id but I am not getting any item show up

Answer (score 0):

To use a dynamic list for a **Shadcn UI** *Select* component and loop over them as **SelectItems**, you can follow these steps:

```js
// Define your dynamic list
const fruits = [
  {
    id: 1,
    label: "Apple",
  },
  // ... (other fruits)
];
```

Use the map function to loop over the dynamic list (fruits) and render each item as a SelectItem.
Ensure to set a unique key for each SelectItem.

```js
// Import the necessary components from the Shadcn UI library.
export function SelectDemo() {
  return (
    <Select>
      <SelectTrigger className="w-[180px]">
        <SelectValue placeholder="Select a fruit" />
      </SelectTrigger>
      <SelectContent>
        <SelectGroup>
          <SelectLabel>Fruits</SelectLabel>
          {/* Use map to loop over the dynamic list */}
          {fruits.map((fruit) => (
            // Make sure to set a unique key for each SelectItem
            <SelectItem key={fruit.id} value={fruit.id}>
              {fruit.label}
            </SelectItem>
          ))}
        </SelectGroup>
      </SelectContent>
    </Select>
  );
}
```

By following these steps, you should be able to create a dynamic Select component that renders items from the dynamic list.